# Writing to a file help in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my atm, it has a pin code protection thing and can basically run like a normal atm, however i need to make it so it remembers you and your balance everytime you log out and in etc. ive tried doing this with a blank text file(nothing is in the text file) and linked it into my code (as you can see) but it doesnt work, im not sure what i have to add etc. any help?

```
balance = float(0)

userInput = None

path = 'N:\ATM.txt'
username = 'some_username'


with open(path, 'r') as file:

    for user in file.readlines():
        if user == username:
           print("welcome back")
print("Hello, Welcome to the ATM")
print("")
print("Please begin with creating an account")

name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")


saved_code = str(raw_input("Please enter a 4 digit pin to use as your passcode: "))


try:
    int(saved_code)
    if len(saved_code)!=4:
        raise
except Exception, e:
    print("Error: Pin is not a valid 4 digit code")
    exit()


totalTrails = 3;
currentTrail = 0;
status = 1;


while currentTrail < totalTrails: 
    user_code =str(raw_input('Please enter the 4 digit pin on your card:'))
    if user_code==saved_code:
        status=0
        break;
    else:
        currentTrail+=1

if status==0:
    print("correct pin!")
else:
    print("You tried to enter a wrong code more than three times.")
    exit();       

print "Hello , welcome to the ATM"

while userInput != "4":
    userInput = raw_input("\n what would you like to do?\n\n     (1)Check balance\n     (2)Insert funds\n" +
    "     (3)Withdraw funds\n     (4)Exit the ATM\n" )                                                                                                                                                                                              

    if userInput == "1":
        print "your balance is", "£" , balance

    elif userInput == "2":
        funds = float(raw_input("Enter how much money you want to add"))
        balance = balance + funds

    elif userInput == "3":
        withdraw = float(raw_input("Enter how much money you want to withdraw..."))
        balance = balance - withdraw

    elif userInput == "4":
        print "Thanks for using the ATM!"
```

Comment: Why `Java` and `Javascript` tag when it is related to `python`??

Comment: What is the point of a _blank_ file? Why don't you write to the file? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file in 'r' mode, which means read only, you should use 'r+' if you want to read and write in it.

You are not writing anything to the file - that's done by write() method - in your case
file.write("string I want to write to the file");

After you are done writing to the file, close it - file.close()

Comment: Always use `with` for files.